# Change cursor on selection/drag inside div?

Tags: css, selection, drag

Here is the example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjmNZ/)

When you drag inside the div the cursor should become a crossahair. It works if I change `div`to `canvas`.

The source:

```
<div id="draw" />

#draw { 
    cursor: pointer;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}

#draw:active { 
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

Why doesn't it work for div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you drag inside a `<div>` element, browser tries to select the content. You could use CSS3 [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) property on your division:

```
#draw { 
    cursor: pointer;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;

    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

#draw:active { 
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/qjmNZ/1/)**